# WPF Report Designer

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, report-designer

Does anybody know of a tutorial or sample code on how to create a simple designer control in WPF?

I am trying to write a simple designer in WPF where users can drag and drop data items (charts & lists) on specific points on a page (e.g. Line 3, Coloumn 24).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx) about a diagram designer in WPF (this is the last part but the entire series if 4 articles long). It's not related to report but might give you a starting point about how to manage items on a surface with drag'n'drop.